# Update bashrc with virtualenv info using Ansible

Tags: bash, ansible, virtualenvwrapper

I have a python virtualenv running on a remote server. I am trying to update the bashrc of the remote server with the following info using Ansible.

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/TestEnvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon my_virtual_env
```

Is there any way to accomplish this using Ansible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Use Ansible `blockinfile` module to maintain the lines in the `.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc`:

   ```
   - name: Ensure virtualenv is sourced from the .bashrc
     blockinfile:
       dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bashrc"
       block: |
         export WORKON_HOME=~/TestEnvs
         source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
         workon my_virtual_env
       marker: '# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK - virtualenv'
       insertbefore: BOF
       create: yes
   ```
2. Or better: create a `.bashrc.d` (or `.bash_profile.d`) directory, replace your `.bashrc` with a call to source all files in the directory:

   ```
   while read filename
   do
     source "$filename"
   done < <(find -L ~/.bashrc.d -type f)
   ```

   and add the above commands as a separate file. Move other commands from the current `.bashrc` to another file and place it in `.bashrc.d` directory.

   This you can easily achieve with `file` and `copy` modules in Ansible.